# ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Syntax error

Tags: c#, datetime, insert, odbc

Hy
I want to insert into ODBC and I have the error:  ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Syntax error.
My code is:

```
string number;

insertStatement = "INSERT INTO " + tabela + " (Data, Fetr, Fldo, Nrdo, Dii) " +
        " VALUES ( "+ "@data" +", 'cc','CD', " +  number + ","+ dii + ")";

       OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(insertStatement, this.connection);             

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@data",OdbcType.DateTime).Value = data;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The problem is with the data, but I cannot figure out what is the problem.
Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Could you specify the field data type for each of the field & data  type for each of the variable (number, dii)?

Comment: DateTime data, double dii, string number - and in the table number is of type number..only I have problems at data...because if I insert without data it works, but when I put data in my insert statement gives me errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with a ? instead of @data in the query, like this:

```
insertStatement = "INSERT INTO " + tabela + " (Data, Fetr, Fldo, Nrdo, Dii) " +
        " VALUES ( ? , 'cc','CD', " +  number + ","+ dii + ")";
```

[Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.parameters%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) says:

> When CommandType is set to Text, the
>   .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC
>   does not support passing named
>   parameters to an SQL statement or to a
>   stored procedure called by an
>   OdbcCommand. In either of these cases,
>   use the question mark (?) placeholder.

**UPDATE**
you could try concatenating your date directly in the insert in this format `{ d '2011-03-10' }` (see [ODBC Datetime Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190234.aspx) for reference) and drop the parameter.

```
insertStatement = "INSERT INTO " + tabela + " (Data, Fetr, Fldo, Nrdo, Dii) " +
            " VALUES ( { d '" +
            data.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") 
             + "' } , 'cc','CD', " +  number + ","+ dii + ")";
```

Comment: if I put ? instead of @data i have the error: ERROR [22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Data type mismatch.

Comment: @user599977 I've added a suggestion. See if it works that way